# How to tap on a button under a Spacer SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a `ZStack` in which there are separate 2 VStacks. The `First VStack` has a  Navlink, and a `Second` one has a ScrollView to enable scrolling over that button. Also `Second VStack` has a `dynamic Spacer` on top (that changes based on scrolling).

When I put `VStack with a Navlink` over `VStack with a ScrollView`, problem is seemed to be solved (Navlink work), but then `on scroll` they are visible and tapable on ScrollView.(button has to be under)

## Problem:

How to tap on the `Navlink` if they are in the `First VStack` and the ***second*** one has a `ScrollView` on `VStack with Navlink` ?

My code:

```
@State var scroll:CGFloat = 350

ZStack{
    VStack(spacing: 0){
        ScrollView{
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: scroll )
            VStack{
                Text("123")
            }
        }
    }.background(.black)
    
    // second
    VStack{
        Spacer()
            .frame(height: 200)
        HStack{
            NavigationLink(destination: TransferView()){
                VStack (spacing: -10){
                    
                    Image("transferBlack")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width:100, height: 100)
                    Text("Transfer")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not testable

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for the answer. Just edited. If there are any questions - just ask.

Comment: @MaksymRohovskoi Please show respect to other users and format the code in your question properly

Comment: @AshleyMills is everything fine with the code now? It should be testable.